# Using Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to do Javascript, and it doesn't work. This is what comes out in the web page:
[image: pic]
, not the actual thing it would display when it runs properly.
 I have the notepad++ 6.6.7 version.

Here's how I did it:

1. Write the code.[image: pic]
2. Change the language to Javascript.[image: pic]
3. Run it in Google Chrome.[image: pic]

And this is my result!?!?:
[image: pic]

Am I not using Notepad++ correctly or my code has an error in it? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should make your file .html

Comment: There's no Javascript in sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers will render HTML and execute JavaScript in HTML documents not text documents as your filename of `thing.txt` suggests.

If you're experimenting try one of these sites: http://jsbin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 4):

Rename your file to `somefilename.html`.

Answer (score 4):

You're saving your file as `thing.txt`. Save it as `thing.html`.
Also you're saying that you are working on javascript, but your code only contains html, so even you try to choose the language as javascript, javascript format won't work (but first save it as html file).